# how can I pass the text which user entered in the text box from the view to controller in asp.net application.My view in razor or cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am beginner to asp.net and mvc.
I have tried this html code in the cshtml (view). I create a class property "filtervalue" in model which I pass in the

```
html.textboxfor(m => Model.Filtertype)
```

I expect that the `model.filtertype` should contain the value which user entered in the textbox but while debugging `Model.Filtertype` is null.

```
   <div id="exportDiv" disabled class="bt-exportdiv">    
        <p>Export By:</p>

        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.Filtertype, 1, new { onclick = "ByUdidRadioButtonChecked()", id = "udid", name = "export" })
        <span>Udid</span>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.Filtertype, 2, new { onclick = "ByUserRadioButtonChecked()", id = "byuser", name = "export" })
        <span>By user</span>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.Filtertype, 4, new { onclick = "AllUsersRadioButtonChecked()", id = "exportall", name = "export" })
        <span>Export All (All Users In the Company)</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FilterValue, new { style = "width:375px", onclick = "GetFilterTypeValue()", placeholder = "", @class = "form-input", id = "SearchTextbox", name = "filter-text" })
         <input type="submit" value="Export" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("UserExcelExports", "User")'">
    </div>
```

This is my model class where I created two properties `FilterValue` and `FilterText`:

```
public class UserGrid : _VerticalLayoutViewModel     
{
        public int Filtertype { get; set; }
        public string FilterValue { get; set; }
}
```

This the controller method where I am using the model properties

```
public MemoryStream ExcelExportforUser()                                                               
{
    UserRequestContext requestContext = WebUtils.GetUserRequestContext(ControllerContext.HttpContext);
    SiteContext siteContext = WebUtils.GetSiteContext(ControllerContext.HttpContext);`
    
    IUserService _userService = (IUserService)GetService(ServiceId.UserService);
    List<User> tmpUsers = new List<User>();           
    Company company = null;
    long CompanyId = 0;
    UserGrid filter = new UserGrid();
    int filtertype = filter.Filtertype;
    string filtervalue = filter.FilterValue;

    ICompanyService CompanyService = (ICompanyService)GetService(ServiceId.CompanyService);
    if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session[WebConstants.COMPANY_ID] != null && long.Parse(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session[WebConstants.COMPANY_ID].ToString()) != 0)
    {
        CompanyId = long.Parse(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session[WebConstants.COMPANY_ID].ToString());
    }
    else if (WebUtils.GetUser(ControllerContext.HttpContext) != null)
    {
        CompanyId = WebUtils.GetUser(ControllerContext.HttpContext).CompanyId;
    }

    try
    {
        tmpUsers = _userService.GetFilteredUsersList(CompanyId, requestContext.SiteKey, filtertype, filtervalue, requestContext);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //catch and handle any exception in service
        LogWriter.WriteAuditLog(ex.Message, LogLevel.ERROR, ex, requestContext: RequestContext);
    }
```

In the controller I want to pass the filteredvalue as a parameter to a method.

Comment: You have the controller action created where the view will submit the data?

Comment: @chetanRanpariya yes it is created

Comment: I see that you have very little to know knowledge on how to use Model, View and POST controller action to get data from view to controller. The solution to your issue will take an entire article/blog post to explain and there are plenty of such articles/blog posts available on your favorite search engine... I suggest to learn from them and use that knowledge to solve your issue and ask question here if you face any specific issue in that..

Answer (score 0):

Where is your form to pass values from view to controller
first you should have a form in the view and submit the form to controller with POST or GET methods, next receive values in the controller